# Hive MQ connect request URL

Tags: servlets, filter, mqtt, hivemq

i wanted to know. when we connect to a hiveMQ broker via URL( tcp:\localhost:1883), and then client. connect(MqttConnectOptions), which have username and password. can this whole URL be accessed like tcp:\localhost:1883=username+password? something like this please, i need to know. i want to use it to servlet filter. client->filter->hiveMQ broker like this. can it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

HiveMQ is a MQTT Broker and not a Servlet Container, so Servlet Filters are not possible. If you want to intercept the MQTT message, you can use the HiveMQ plugin system. The documentation is available here: http://www.hivemq.com/docs/plugins/latest/

It's not possible to add the username password to the connection URL, you should use the standard MQTT mechanisms for authentication and authorization. You can read more about that here: http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-security-fundamentals-authentication-username-password